# Astronomical scale

Tags: scale

Does anyone know a work around for the issue of astronomical scale? I'm trying to animate a spaceship around a planet but the center coordinate is too far and the ship looses precision due to the floating point. It seems that you can't move a model too far at all before this problem occurs.

Comment: What about the good old "if you can't make it, fake it"? Make the planet(s) first in a manageable scale, render it out and use it as backdrop for your spaceship?